# Will repeatedly looting villages bankrupt the AI players' economy?

Tags: mount-and-blade

I've put together a fast, brutal party of slavers, and we love to burn villages.  My dream is to undermine the economy of Rhodoks so badly that the other kingdoms devour their lands.

However, I'm not certain that such plunder actually affects the AI players.  Does anyone know?  I'm suspicious because of things like the AI magically spawning new soldiers into a garrison, without any lord recruiting them, training them, or moving them in.  I assume that the AI uses many shortcuts.  Since I've never seen an AI lord enter a village (and collect his taxes), it makes me wonder if that economy matters at all.

Comment: Based on my experience, I'm almost 100% sure raiding villages doesn't hinder the AI at all.

Comment: After many months of raiding, there seemed to be little effect.  Unsatisfied, I made this crude prototype: http://www.andrewmccormick.org/Slaver%20Ape/slaver%20ape.html  It's not really a test of whether or not that strategy will work in M&B.  Rather, it's just to provide the experience.

Comment: In my experience lords spend quite time to train soldiers but definitely looks like they get them from no were. Some times I destroyed a and lord he escapes and after getting in and out a town he come back with one hundred soldiers or so...

Answer (score 1):

While I do believe that the AI does randomly obtain their soldiers (In a slightly reasonable manner), I thouroughly believe that raiding villages/caravans does affect the economy.

Villages are required to make produce and send them to cities to turn into other goods, or sell there. The villages increase their prosperity by selling goods, and the cities do aswell by selling the goods in the city. Some of these goods are exported through caravans to make more money. More goods to sell means more money. No goods coming from villages means less or no money.

So ultimately, raiding villages and caravans does affect AI and human players.

Answer (score 1):

Even if M&B simulates the economy where amount of goods produced by villages determines amount of goods that are sent to the cities (which I doubt) raiding may not influence economy as much as you think. Because rhodok parties also loot villages, thus supplying local market with the spoils. Also just one party that goes around burning villages'n'rapin' cattle can't possibly damage the economy enough to be devastating to the point where the country is going to be picked apart by its enemies.